# Alertify confirms and submits a form automatically without clicking OK

Tags: javascript, jquery, alertify

I'm creating a blog with bootstrap and I have a form to submit categories:

```
<form action="categories.php" id="category-form" class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="category" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Category</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" name="category" class="form-control" id="category" placeholder="Category">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" id="btn-submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add Category">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

When I press the form button "Add Category" the dialog appears but after a few seconds it submits itself immediately and the dialog disappears without clicking the buttons "yes" or "no", searching the web I found some solutions but doesn't work for me. The code I use for Alertify JS is the following:

```
$("#btn-submit").on("click", function(){
    alertify.confirm("This is an alert dialog?", function(e){
        if (e) {
            alertify.success("Category was saved.")
        } else {
            alertify.error("Category not saved.");
        }
    });
return false;
});
```

I also try `event.preventDefault();`:

```
$("#btn-submit").on("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    alertify.confirm("This is an alert dialog?", function(e){
        if (e) {
            $("#category-form").submit();
            alertify.success("Category was saved.")
            return true;
        } else {
            alertify.error("Category not saved.");
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

But does not work as well. Any help please... Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

try something like this. i think you want the confirmation before submitting the form so added the confirm message part. hope it will help.

```
$("#category-form").submit(function (e) {
            var result = confirm("Are you sure ?");
            if(result){
                // do something
            } else {
                alertify.error("Error mesage.");
                e.preventDefault(); // this will prevent from submitting the form.
                }
        });
```

Comment: Thank you for the response @vitally, I tried your code and apparently it works very well, the only problem in the confirm dialog is not executing the Alertify JS plugin, but thanks for your answer, if you have another solution is very welcome. =)

Comment: try avoid alertify. use default alert box or if you are using the bootstrap framework try use the modal box.

Comment: Thank you @vitally, I think that is the best option

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following code:

You need to remove `type="submit"` from your `button`. Otherwise it submits the form by default.

**HTML:**

```
<form action="categories.php" id="category-form" class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="category" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Category</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" name="category" class="form-control" id="category" placeholder="Category">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <input type="button" id="btn-submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add Category">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

**JQuery Code:**

```
//your button click code
$("#btn-submit").on("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    alertify.confirm("This is an alert dialog?", function(e){
        if (e) {
            $("#category-form").submit();
            alertify.success("Category was saved.")
            return true;
        } else {
            alertify.error("Category not saved.");
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you @vijayP for your quick response and yes the first part is avoiding the submission but for some reason when is returning false the form is not saving the data. I'm a little bit confused.

Comment: oh..thats correct. Will update the answer in some time.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I tried your code but does not work, apparently the form submits but without data, I used AJAX and PHP to save the data but does not work too, I appreciate your help @vijayP

Comment: I start thinking is a problem with the Alertify JS plugin. I will use probably the JavaScript nature confirm dialog =D

Answer (score 0):

alertify basically take 4 arguments in confirm function

```
alertify.confirm(title, message, onconfirm, oncancel);
```

You don't have to do `if(e)`this code

```
$("#formID").on("click", function(){
    alertify.confirm("This is an alert dialog?", function(e){
        if (e) {
            alertify.success("Category was saved.")
        } else {
            alertify.error("Category not saved.");
        }
    });
return false;
});
```

will now become

```
$("#formID").submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
 alertify.confirm('Confirm Title', 'Confirm Message', function(){
   // call the function that will handle your form submission may be ajax don't write $('#fomr').submit() becasue it will start an endless loop through this function   
  }, function(){ 
    // when user click cancel
  });

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     Ok, This was posted and answered a long time ago. But as I was developing asp net 
    core in 2020, I came across AlertifyJS. I like the library. A solution for this 
    issue is:
    1) I used <button>
    2) I used e.preventdefault()
    3) I used ('#category-form').submit() 
    4) Make sure you add id='category-form' in your form and also and id for button. 
    5) Use button and not input type=submit. 
     There could be a difference in how they work. 
     The difference is that <button> can have content, 
     whereas <input> cannot (it is a null element).

        $('#btn-submit').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alertify.confirm('Save Category', 'Do you want to proceed?', function (e) 
            {
                if (e) {
                    $("#category-form").submit();
                    alertify.success('Category Saved Successfully.');
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    alertify.error("Category was not saved.");
                    return false;
                }                   
            }, function () { alertify.error('Cancel') });
        });
```

Comment: Another option an interesting one especially to not trigger page behind method in ASP net core Razor page is to code as below:$('#btn-submit').on('click', function () {
                if (confirm('Do you want to proceed?')) {
                    alert('Thanks for confirming');
                    return true;
                } else {
                    alert('Why did you press cancel? You should have confirmed');
                    return false;
                }
               
                });